# EasyOCR not able to recognize characters in the box

Tags: python, ocr, text-extraction

I am using `easyocr` for text extraction from the image. I am able to extract the details properly however there is one portion of the image which Easyocr could not able to extract properly even the image is clear.

Attached is the portion of the image which is not getting extracted properly.

[image]

In the image shown, some of the characters are extracted and some are missed.In this case S190 is extracted only.
Can anyone help how can i extract this number as it is using easyocr.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do similar job.I recommended u could try `PaddleOCR`.I use your image to test got better result

```
S   0.91
1   0.957
2   0.962
0   0.929
9   0.666
（4） 0.802
```

If u still want a better result.I suggest you could try to split to little images by the black line.ocr every little image then got result.

Comment: I have tried removing horizontal and vertical lines and then doing the extraction but that also did not worked for me.

Comment: I mean not removing lines,split pieces like 's' is a image and '1' is a image something like that .You could aslo try to use online service like GCP ocr,It will get more  accuracy result,but it's ocr result  they can't be 100% right.

Comment: It's also ok you could use mutil ocr service try combination a most reliable answer.Normally all the ocr sevice will tell u the char position